# Absorption rate vs. Einstein Absorption Coefficient

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-optics, spectroscopy, absorption

I am trying to understand the absorption rate (or absorption probability density), which is defined as
$$p_{ab}=\frac{\sigma c}{V}, $$
where $\sigma$ is absorption (transition) cross section and $V$ is the volume of the cavity and $c$ is the speed of light.

The thing is that sometimes people call this quantity $p_{ab}$ as Einstein absorption coefficient $B_{12}$, but clearly this is not 'the' Einstein coefficient, because $p$ has a dimensions of $[1/s]$ but $B_{12}$ has different units, $[m^3J^{-1}s^{-2}]$. Also, $B_{12}$ is defined as
$$B_{12}=\frac{\sigma c}{\hbar \omega}. $$

Questions:

1. What is the difference between $B_{12}$ and $p_{ab}$, fundamentally speaking? They both describe the absorption, but in what terms are they different?
2. I am looking in the internet and books but I can not find the derivation of $p_{ab}$. Could someone please show how it its derived, or give a source where does it come from?